# OneDrive SDK - Visual Basic

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, onedrive

I'm trying to make two application (one for desktop and one for WP8.1) which store data in *.xml file. My goal is to make both application to use same shared file. My idea was to put file on OneDrive, and each app when starts, will download file to local folder, change data, and upload to OneDrive again. 
I would like to use OneDrive SDK, but I cannot find any manual how to do it in Visual Basic.

So may question is - is it possible to get my goal using OneDrive SDK?

If Yes maybe You can share sample code or guide how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new .NET SDK out for OneDrive: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp

It doesn't have a method built in for chunked upload but you should be able to use simple [item upload](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/docs/items.md#uploading-contents) and simple [item download](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/docs/items.md#downloading-contents) for your scenario.